# PHPLint class do not has a parent

Tags: php, phplint

I'm using PHPLint to lint my Laravel code, most things are fine, but I am having an issue with the `__construct()` linting.

I am using the very common `parent::__construct();` line, but PHPLint is telling me that the classes 'do not has parent'. Anyone come across this, and solved it?

Using SublimeLinter in Sublime Text.

Comment: Does it have parent?

Comment: `class CheckoutController extends BaseController` and in `BaseController` there is indeed a `__construct` method. I am using Sublime text with SublimeLinter. Probably should have mentioned that